# why MSSQL SERVER return question marks, when I execute query in PHP?

Tags: php, sql-server

My Databese server is MSSQL SERVER and I connect to it with PHP's PDO class, connection is successful but when I execute query I receive question marks for all text type fields.

I have "UTF-8" in HTML Charset, My database collation is "Latin1_General_BIN" and fields type is nvarchar(50).

If you have some solition for this problem, please reply.

Answer (score 0):

I serched around and found a post on php.net.

Maybe this can help (from http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php#98659 )

This works to get UTF8 data from MSSQL:

```
<?php
$db = new PDO('dblib:host=your_hostname;dbname=your_db;charset=UTF-8', $user, $pass);
?>
```

You can try using different `charset` arguments to see if any works.

Comment: Tank you danishgoal but your answer is not correct because "charset=UTF-8" works only for MySQL and don't for MSSQL SERVER.

Comment: @IceMan I haven't tried this, I only posted this as someone (see the link) posted that it worked for them. And yes it is mentioned to be working with MSSQL, But it is via PDO_DBLIB. Are you using PDO_ODBC ?